# Search for tweets within a user timeline using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Using twitter4j is it possible to search within a particular user's timeline for tweets containing a specific keyword? I know I can use the Query object to query for tweets. But it does not have the option to set the user. Hence I think we need some other way to go. I googled a lot and could not find a way to do so using Twitter4j.

So is it at all possible?

Comment: Get user's timeline, and then search the keywords in the tweets you get

Comment: @RamananR thats the obvious way. But I was looking for something from the api that directly gives us that facility.

Comment: I don't think its possible